# Mark folder as generated in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, generated-code

Within our app we include classes that are generated by our backend.
We keep them in a separate folder within our project. A new colleague overlooked the fact that these classes were located in the `generated` folder and started editing these.

So that made me wonder if there is a way to tell Android Studio that the `generated` folder contains generated classes and should not be edited. Much like if you try to edit a file under the `build` folder.

[image: Android Studio build folder warning]

I could off course just add a comment to every file, but it would be much more clear if Android Studio showed a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the projekt explorer (the one which comes up when you click `ALT` + `1`) select the project or project files view.
Next right click any folder and select `Mark Directory as`, which is in the bottom part of the context menu. There may already be options displayed like `Sources Root` or `Generated Sources Root`.
If these options don't show up mark it as `Excluded`. For folders inside the excluded directory you should then be able to mark them as `Generated Sources Root`.

Not sure why you can't always choose from all the options...

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this to work. The downside is that the warning only shows up after I've edited the file (but I can live with that). The other thing is that this setting is stored within the .idea and it's excluded from our repository. Is there an easy way to share this setting with the team, maybe with some kind of export?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any option. But you could consider adding part of the .idea folder to your vcs. Check JetBrains [FAQ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems).